# Exported const should have a comment

Tags: go

I'm trying to export a constant from a go like this:

```
package log

const (
    FATAL = iota // fatal errors
    ERROR = iota // errors might happend
    DEBUG = iota // debug mode
) // const for logging levels
```

But I'm getting golint error :

```
exported const FATAL should have comment  (or a comment on this block) or be unexported (golint)
```

And it's right I'm getting later error in getting access to log.FATAL etc.

Comment: Stop whatever u are doing, read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), and then go back to work.  Else the linters are going to eat you alive!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Comments for documentation always immediately preceded what they are documenting.

```
const (
    // FATAL represents fatal errors
    FATAL = iota
```

Answer (score 17):

Also you can provide a comment for a set of constants:

```
// Log level
const (
    Debug = iota
    Trace
    Info
    Warn
    Error
    Panic
    Fatal
)
```

Comment: Hey, I got a brief question here. let's say I have a group of constants related, and one that is used totally apart. Let me do a quick example:


// headers
const(
Someheader="header1"
AnotherOne="header2"
ExtraOne="header3"
)
//important number not related
const magicNumber=2


should that number go inside the const() with an individual comment or it's better to keep it separate?

Comment: (IMHO) Personally I put related constants inside separate const statements. That way using `iota` is meaningful and comments can be managed more precisely.